# Using an if else statement with a string condition inside of a nested for loop

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

I am doing an exercise in which i have to create a trivia game, i need 5 questions and 5 answers and to store them using arrays, which i have managed to do just fine so far, then i have to create at least 2 methods to make the code more readable, which i will do at the end.

I'm currently trying to code the part that does input and output and checks if the input matches the answers.

I'm struggling with the if else statement inside of the nested for loop:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = null;

for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(questions[i]);
    input = scanner.next();

    for (int j = 0; j < answers.length; j++)
    {
        if (input.toLowerCase().equals(answers[j]))
        {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
    }
```

The output i want to have is:

```
Scariest animal?
Lion
Correct!
Biggest animal?
Elephant
Wrong!
Smallest animal?
Tardigrade
Correct!
```

But what im getting is:

```
Scariest animal?
Lion
Correct!
Wrong!
Wrong!
Biggest animal?
Elephant
Wrong!
Wrong!
Wrong!
Smallest animal?
Tardigrade
Wrong!
Wrong!
Correct
```

The if else statement in the nested loop is throwing me off, i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: if it is correct, you should "stop" the internal loop and go to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Also, the `input = scanner.next();` should be inside the internal loop. If an answer is wrong, you should be able to retry giving an answer instead of giving the same answer again ;)

Comment: I think you found your candidate for one of the merhods-  `GetAnswerForQuestion(q)`  :)

Comment: I might be wrong, but instead of iterating over all answers for an input, shouldn't you just compare it to `answer[i]`? Because currently you only check, whether the given `input` is an answer to *any* of your questions, but not necessarily the one you currently asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your inner loop. For each question, you're iterating through all the answers, and for each answer, you're printing "Correct" or "Wrong" without considering if the current answer is the correct one for the current question.

You can use a boolean variable to keep track of whether the input was correct for the current question or not.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = null;
boolean isCorrect;

for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(questions[i]);
    input = scanner.next();
    isCorrect = false; // Reset isCorrect for each new question

    for (int j = 0; j < answers.length; j++)
    {
        if (input.toLowerCase().equals(answers[j]))
        {
            isCorrect = true;
            break; // Exit the loop if a correct answer is found
        }
        
    }
    
    if (isCorrect) {
       System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else {
       System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
```

Alternatively, you can avoid using the inner loop comparing the input answer with the correct answer associated with a specific question (indexed by i):

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(questions[i]);
    input = scanner.next();

    if (input.toLowerCase().equals(answers[i])) {
       System.out.println("Correct!");
    } else {
       System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
}
```